# Как заставить IE понимать "max-device-width" в медиа-запросах?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, адаптивная-верстка

Как заставить IE понимать `max-device-width` в медиа-запросах?

Для `max-width` можно использовать picturefill.js, но мне нужно именно `max-device-width`.

Нужно, чтоб в IE заработала такая конструкция:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="/jpg/mos01s1.jpg" media="(min-width: 1920px)">
    <source srcset="/jpg/mos01s2.jpg" media="(max-width: 1919px) and (min-width: 1680px)">
    <source srcset="/jpg/mos01s3.jpg" media="(max-width: 1679px) and (min-width: 1600px)">
    <source srcset="/jpg/mos01s4.jpg" media="(max-width: 1599px) and (min-width: 1366px)">
    <source srcset="/jpg/mos01s5.jpg" media="(max-width: 1365px) and (min-width: 1280px)">
    <source srcset="/jpg/mos01s6.jpg" media="(max-width: 1279px)">
    <img srcset="/jpg/mos01s1.jpg">
</picture>
```